# Brand Names In Root, With Htaccess

Tags: mysql, .htaccess

I have about 2000 brand name in my mysql database.. and i want to give link to these brand name's such as:

www.example.com/cocacola, www.example.com/pepsi, www.example.com/mercedes etc.

I'm using these htaccess lines:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$/?$ ?brand=$1&type=about
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$/news ?brand=$1&type=news
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$/contact ?brand=$1&type=contact
```

but... for example, if someone calls

**www.example.com/xxxx/yyyy?daa=zzzz**

or anything except any other pointed rules in htaccess:

the browser is trying to find the brand: **xxxx/yyyy?daa=zzzz** ...

do you have any advise about usage of brand links as like example.com/pepsi ?

(as i said before, there are 2000+ brand name, i cant write one by one)

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Why would the user enter `www.example.com/xxxx/yyyy?daa=zzzz` into their browser? I thought you were trying to rewrite your 'ugly' variable-based URLs to 'pretty' URLs? What do `xxxx`, `yyyy`, `daa` and `zzzz` in your example translate to?

Comment: no no.. actualy; i just dont want to make some duplicated pages for google spiders.. xxxx/yyyy?daa=zzzz  is just an example.. whatever you write (with undeclerated rules in htaccess), the browser says: there is no brand name with this name :S (it must go to 404 page)

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly you are trying to do, sorry. /: What is the problem that you are trying to find a solution for? What is happening now that you don't want to happen? You started describing your problem above with "the browser is trying to find..." but then didn't finish explaining what happens after that, or what you don't want to happen next.